# How connect to created stream from another script?

Tags: php, sockets, websocket

A websocket server is created in one script

```
$server_socket = stream_socket_server('tcp://0.0.0.0:9000', $errno, $message);
```

How to connect and send data to this stream from another local PHP script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$fp = stream_socket_client("tcp://x.x.x.x:9000", $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php